# What is backpressure in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I can't find any information on what backpressure is in Erlang docs.  If you could point me to some docs, or elaborate on what it is, it would be helpful.  I have looked at [Wikipedia's Back pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_pressure) entry, but I'm not 100% sure how this relates to Erlang, though.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a reference to managing flow rate by queuing messages for processes, but it would help if you'd give some context for where you saw a reference to "back pressure" with respect to Erlang.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Back pressure in erlang refers normally to blocking on input data as a method for handling Overload

Check [**this blog post**](http://ferd.ca/queues-don-t-fix-overload.html) that uses it in an example.

Also of interest will be

1. The [**slide**](http://www.erlang-factory.com/static/upload/media/139446925618046fredhebert.pdf) and [**video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IuK2NvxjvWY&list=UUKrD_GYN3iDpG_uMmADPzJQ) of the talk **"Planning for Overload"** by Fred Hebert
2. The free ebook "[**Stuff Goes Bad: Erlang in Anger**](https://s3.amazonaws.com/erlang-in-anger/text.v1.0.2.pdf)" by Fred Hebert